# svg / snapsvg creating text that bends

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Okay so i am relatively new to both [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)and [snap.svg](/questions/tagged/snap.svg).

However i am trying out the different features and how to create all sorts of different `text` elements.

Normal text is not a challenge however i started wondering how do i make text that actually bends?

Say for instance i want to create a text such as this:

[image]

As you can see the text bends.

My Ultimate goal is to use [snap.svg](/questions/tagged/snap.svg)to allow the user to bend the text however I'm not quite sure on how to do this.

Has anyone attempted to bend text and is able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a Snap.svg and javascript. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG is necessary to define a path with curved dimensions.

Here an example:

```html
<svg height="70" width="300">
  <defs>
    <path id="myTextPath" d="M 30 55 q 100 -46 240 0" />
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="70" width="300" fill="#292425" />
  <text x="10" y="100" style="font-size: 18px; stroke: #E6E6E6;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">INVITATION TIL BRYLLUP</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Update:

And this is a simple example where a user can bend the text, in real time.

Using VanillaJS (Javascript) and Snap.svg.

```js
(function() {
  var orientation = document.getElementById("orientation");
  orientation.addEventListener("change", function() {
    bendText(this.value);
  });

  function bendText(value) {
    var snap = Snap("#myTextPath");
    snap.attr("d", "M 30 55 q 100 " + value * -1 + " 240 0");
  }
})();
```

```css
input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
  writing-mode: bt-lr;
  /* IE */
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  /* WebKit */
  width: 8px;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
<input id="orientation" type="range" orient="vertical" value="46" max="46" min="-46" />
<svg height="70" width="300">
  <defs>
    <path id="myTextPath" d="M 30 55 q 100 -46 240 0" />
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="70" width="300" fill="#292425" />
  <text x="10" y="100" style="font-size: 18px; stroke: #E6E6E6;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">INVITATION TIL BRYLLUP</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/j0f10p09/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a textpath attribute, which takes a path and positions the string along it.

```js
var s = Snap(500,500); 

var path = "M 100 200 C 200 100 300   0 400 100 C 500 200 600 300 700 200 C 800 100 900 100 900 100";

var text = s.text(50,50,'Hi there, Im a textpath that curves along a path string')
            .attr({ 'textpath': path })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
```

[docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.text)